# Adding colors and styles to a Wikipedia username

Tags: wikipedia, username, customization

I’ve noticed on numerous occasions that some users on Wikipedia have names that include colors and styles while most do not. There are a bunch of examples of various kinds on [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:VisualEditor/Default_State_RFC) (I’ve compiled a smattering of examples in the image below).

How do they color and style their usernames? Do they include special markup or CSS in the actual name?

---

[image: Mash-up of examples of Wikipedia signatures with colors, styles, boxes, etc.]

Comment: Have a look at [Wikipedia:Signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:CUSTOMSIG).

Answer (score 3):

I looked at the source for a page that contains such examples, and it looks like what they are doing is to use the *signature* field in the user-profile settings to (below). You can enter markup (the examples I saw were using the deprecated `<font>` tag and `style` attribute). Then when you edit a Wikipedia page and add the `~~~~` to add your signature, it will include the specified styles.

Also, svick pointed out a [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:CUSTOMSIG#Appearance_and_color) that gives guidelines on what is an is not acceptable in a customized signature.

[image: Screenshot of Wikipedia’s signature field]